# Find $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sin 1+2\sin \frac{1}{2}+\cdots+n\sin \frac{1}{n}}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

> Find $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sin 1+2\sin \frac{1}{2}+\cdots+n\sin \frac{1}{n}}{n}.$$

This is a recent exam question, which I couldn't figure out in the exam. My guess is it doesn't exist.

Comment: That is a neat exam question :)

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main
page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730)
for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For small $|x|$ we have $\sin(x)\approx x$.
Hence 
\[  i \cdot \sin\frac{1}{i} \approx 1  \]
for big values of $i$. 
Hence 
\[ \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n i\cdot \sin\frac{1}{i} }{n}\approx \frac{n}{n}=1\]

Comment: Thanks. Seems so easy now. Should have figured it out.

Comment: I also thought of that, but even if it is intuitive I don't think it's really rigorous.. Could you provide a more detalied answer?

Comment: @ant think of the power series of $\sin$, due to taylor we know $\sin(x)=x-\frac{\xi^3}{6}$ where $\xi\in (-x,x)$

Comment: I meant, you substitute $ i \cdot \sin{\frac{1}{i}}$ with 1 for every i, but that only works for "big enough" i... isn't this something to take into consideration?

Comment: @Ant nope because of taylor we can write it as $$\sum_{i=1}^n i \cdot \sin\left( \frac{1}{i}\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n i \cdot \left( \frac{1}{i} -\frac{1}{\xi^3}\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n 1- \frac{i}{6 \cdot \xi^3}$$ And hence $$\sum_{i=1}^n i \cdot \sin\left( \frac{1}{i}\right) > \sum_{i=1}^n 1- \frac{1}{6 i^2}$$

Comment: awesome.. thank you :-)

Answer (score 68):

Another more general approach:

$$a_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} a\implies \frac{a_1+...+a_n}n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}a$$

And since

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\,n\,\sin\frac1n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin\frac1n}{\frac1n}=1\;\;\ldots\ldots$$

Comment: These are the so called Cesaro averages. If a series converges the Cesaro averages converge to the same value.

Answer (score 19):

Or we can use [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) to find that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\sin 1+2\sin \frac{1}{2}+\cdots+n\sin \frac{1}{n}}{n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(n+1)\sin {\frac{1}{n+1}}}{1}=1.$$

This is similar with @DonAntonio's solution.

Answer (score 17):

Start by writing it in summation form. That is,

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i\sin(1/i)}{n}
$$
Now, $\sin(1/i)<1/i$ for $i\in\mathbb{N}$. Furthermore, $\sin(1/i)>\frac1i-\frac1{6i^3}$ for $i\in\mathbb{N}$.
Now, we squeeze the result by noting that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac1n = 1
$$
and
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1-\frac1{6i^2}}n = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac1n-\frac1{6i^2n} = 1
$$
Therefore, we have that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i\sin(1/i)}{n}=1
$$

Comment: Because $\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}6+O(x^5)$, and so $\sin(x)/x = 1-\frac{x^2}6+O(x^4)$.

Comment: Nevermind I didn't read carefully enough

Comment: @Wishingwell the dummy variable is $i$ and not $n$. $n$ is a constant in the expression.

Comment: @Wishingwell : $$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1n=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n1=\frac1n\cdot n=1$$